# Can I set value for specific property of generic object in generic function in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a function which is responsible to save generic object like that:

```
public <T> T save(final T o){
        return (T) getCurrentSession().save(o);
    }
```

My object have some common specific properties such as createDate, createId, updateId, updateDate,...
Can I set these properties in my save function like:

`o.setProperty("propertyName", value)`

Comment: Note that if your `getCurrentSession()` is referring to a Hibernate Session, the legacy Hibernate APIs are generally deprecated in favor of the standard JPA APIs (`EntityManager` and friends).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put bounds on the type parameter T to allow you to call methods on it from an interface you have defined:

```
    interface MyObject {
        void createDate();
        void createId();
        ...
    }
    public <T extends MyObject> T save(final T o){
        o.createDate();
        return (T) getCurrentSession().save(o);
    }
```

Comment: In the particular case illustrated by the post, a sensible name for the interface is likely to be `Audited`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection API to create an universal setter.
A bit ugly, straightforward, not typesafe and too many Object values but still a working solution.

```
public Object setValue(Object classObject, String fieldIdentifier, Object value) {
    Class<?> clazz = classObject.getClass();
    Field retrievedField = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields()) 
  .filter(field -> field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldIdentifier))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);//add an exception here when null

    retrievedField.setAccessible(true);
    retrievedField.set(classObject, value);
    return classObject;
}
```